# How to determine empty search results list on load?

Tags: javascript, youtube-iframe-api

Is there a way to find out whether or not the search results are empty or not without actually playing the videos?

Take this as an example: https://www.youtube.com/embed/?listType=search&list=intitle%3aksdjlfslhdfehadsanfe

Non-empty results are triggering the `UNSTARTED` and `CUED` events on their own after readying up, so that I can query the length of `player.getPlaylist()`.

But empty results are not firing any events after being ready, so I'm unable to consider this case.

I tried playing and pausing the video on `onReady` successively, which would also trigger the `UNSTARTED` event on empty results. Problem with this is it's working unreliably with non-empty lists, sometimes returning empty playlists when they're not.

Comment: why can't you use youtube api? https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/docs/search/list?hl=pt-br

Comment: The YouTube Data API has quota restrictions